# Travelling with bulky jewelry from Saudi Arabia to Kenya,should i put it in checked luggage?

Tags: kenya-airways

Travelling with bulky Jewelry from Saudi Arabia to Kenya, what's needed?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "bulky"? The bulkiest I can imagine would fit in cabin baggage.

Comment: Are you worried about customs?

Comment: Putting valuables in checked luggage is about equivalent to throwing them in the thrash. **Never**!

Comment: My stance on luggage has always been: 1) Checked luggage - Don't expect to see it again (but it's great when you do).  2) Hand luggage - Be prepared to drop it and run during an emergency (EG Emergency exit from a plane). 3) On your person - Everything essential for you to complete your trip (EG Passport, credit cards)

Comment: Are you worried about packing security (making sure the container is strong enough), theft security (making sure the jewelry isn't stolen during the trip), or Kenyan Customs and Immigration upon your arrival?

Answer (score 5):

Never put things of monetary or sentimental value in checked luggage.

It is not very likely to go missing by accident, but still luggage does get lost every now and again.
The real risk is people trying out whether there is something worth stealing and finding your things.

Keep it with you in your carry-on and if it is too bulky for that, see if you can buy extra 'in the cabin' luggage on your flight.
Be early for your flight so you do not run the risk of having to gate check your cabin luggage.

Airlines will not pay for things gone missing from checked in luggage, and most travel insurances will neither.

An other thing is customs, entering a country with valuable items often requires you to pay for it, which will not be as much a problem if it is for a short visit.
Best add details of the value and whether you will stay in Kenya (or whether the items came from Kenya and now return 'home') to your question, so we can help you with those details.

Comment: Depending on the value you may want to purchase an insurance policy on the jewelry. Travel insurance may be a cheaper short term option, but I would read the policy carefully on the limits, and restrictions.